# Differentiation or integration term by term of the Laurent series!

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be an analytic function in the annual $r< |z|<R.$ Then $f(z)$ has the Laurent expansion series in this annual. My question is that: 
Can we derivative (or integrate) term by term from this series to obtain the Laurent series of $f'(z)$?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the Laurent series converges uniformly on $r' \le |z| \le R'$ for every $r < r' < R' < R$, and so does the termwise differentiated series. This justifies that termwise differentiation is valid.